# watch on scope variable of one controller and send it to other controller

Tags: angularjs

I have following requirement.
I have two divs, both are render using custom directives. div1 contains one search textbox and div2 contains tree view control. when user types something in textbox, based on that search word, one service will be called and related data would be bind to TreeView in div2.

Comment: This is not a question and you can't ask to write the full code for you. Please have a look to the help before posting http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I havent asked about the code.I am asking about the approach.the approach i have used in subject line.that is using $watch on scope variable on div1 and call the bridge service. but after research on google i found that this is not the correct way. so wanted to know the alternative approach.

Comment: So at least add your current code we can play with